# Calculate Mean for certain sets of numbers in a dataframe (Pandas,Python3)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
    Group    Importance
    1          100%
    1          100%
    1          50%  
    2          75%
    2          50%
```

I would like to standardize the importance so for each group, the combined importance equals 100% (e.g. each individual cell is divided by the sum of the rest of the numbers in the specific group)

For example:

```
  Group    Importance      Weight
    1          100%        100%/Sum(100%+100%+50%) = 40%
    1          100%        100%/Sum(100%+100%+50%) = 40%
    1          50%         50%/Sum(100%+100%+50%)  = 20%
```

**Therefore, I am trying to get my output as such:**

```
  Group    Importance      Weight
    1          100%        40%
    1          100%        40%
    1          50%         20%
    2          100%        60%
    2          50%         40%
```

My first initial thought was to try something that leverages the power of a for loop in groupby but which *is very wrong* sort of like:

```
for z in df.groupby(['Group']):
    df.apply(lambda row: (row[1]/df['Importance'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the values in your dataframe are numeric (e.g. .50 vs '50%'):

```
df['Weight'] = df.groupby('Group')['Importance'].transform(lambda x: x / sum(x))

>>> df
   Group  Importance  Weight
0      1        1.00     0.4
1      1        1.00     0.4
2      1        0.50     0.2
3      2        0.75     0.6
4      2        0.50     0.4
```